# Change placeholder of input from angularjs directive wake scope model 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have some trouble with my angularjs application. I try to implement a specific directive that make allow to translate my app easily. It works well on my text fields, but it doesn't work on input field to change my placeholder.

To be clear, here you can see some code sample :

http://plnkr.co/edit/GUS2FYCxA6wAOtkoxG66

```
$scope.validform = function() {
   console.log($scope.valuefield);
};
```

As you can see, when i click on the button, my input model "valuefield" is "undefined". Or i want to see the value of the input.
What seems really strange for me is that the directive change the placeholder, but do not touch at the model.

I think I have to be more specific on the scope definition of the directive, or to use some $watch function but I am not sure how.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finally it was pretty easy.
I only had to change my directive parameter from

```
scope : true
```

to

```
scope : false
```

By doing this, my directive is using the exact same scope than the controller. So The scope controller is not change and steal working as it should be.